# Computing a differential

Tags: calculus

I would like to compute the following differential:

$$\frac{dH}{dB_d}$$
where
$$H  = 10^{(\log_{10}(x)A + B))}$$ 
and
$$B_d = e^{(C + D\ln(x))}e^{(E + F/x)}.$$ 
Here, $A,B,C,D,E$ and $F$ are constants. $\log_{10}$ is the base $10$ logarithm and $\ln$ is the natural logarithm.

Can I do the following:
$$\frac{dH}{dB_d} = \frac{dH}{dx}\frac{dx}{dB_d} = \frac{dH/dx}{dB_d/dx}?$$

Thanks!

Comment: Please format your mathematics using Mathjax, as explained in the FAQ, so it is readable to the rest of us.

Comment: @user308827 above a start with formatting this that you could take further and refine.

Comment: Many thanks! al-Hwarizmi, I used your formatting for the remaining equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks OK to me.

Also note that the base of logs
is usually written as subscript
with the "log" escaped.
For example, $\log_{10}$ is $\log_{10}$.

Comment: many thanks! This was helpful.